# Grub rescue, no installation cd

Tags: grubrescue

i deleted Ubuntu 14.10 partition by disc management in widows 7 and after restart i cant access windows anymore. it says "no such partition. entering rescue mode. grub rescue." i have no installation cd for windows and satisfied with Ubuntu. windows was my primary os. i have important documents and need to work as quick as possible, just don't know what to do! HELP PLEASE!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: @Juli Do you have an Ubuntu livecd?

Comment: @ Wilhelm Erasmus, i do have a cd, i tried but not installed Ubuntu and saved my files, but still need the pc to work!